# install phpUnit via pear or composer

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit, composer-php, pear

I'm new to `Zend Framework 2.0`, after reading the documentation I know that we can install `phpUnit` via `Pear` or via `composer` ?

Please explain to me some differences between them, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Composer. The main difference is that Composer installs phpunit within your application, whereas pear installs it on the server. The advantage of the composer approach is that you can have different versions of phpunit used by different applications.